# Updating multiple employee records

Tags: sql, sql-server

All, Need a help in one of the queries.

We have employee records.

```
Employeeid,dept,startdate.enddate.

Sam,IT,2013-10-12, 9999-12-31
```

Now, when employee change the department, we have a new record. So,

```
Employeeid,dept,startdate.enddate.

Sam,IT,2013-10-12, 2014-01-03

Sam,Finance,2014-01-04, 9999-12-31
```

So, it will update, end date to -1 date when new record comes.

Some employee has one row (never changed the dept), some have two or three rows. Tried the query but not working. Any help.

```
UPDATE employee_tbl T5
SET T5.END_DT = (

SELECT T1.START_DT - 1 DAY
  FROM employee_tbl T1,
(
SELECT COUNT(*), employee_id
  FROM employee_tbl
GROUP BY employee_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) TMP
WHERE (TMP.employee_id = T1.employee_id)
    AND T1.START_DT = (SELECT MAX (T3.START_DT) FROM employee_tbl T3
    WHERE T1.employee_ID = T3.employee_ID)
    AND T1.employee_id = 'sam334'

ORDER BY T1.employee_id, T1.START_DT DESC)

WHERE T5.employee_ID = 'sam334'   
    AND T5.START_DT = 
    (SELECT MIN (T4.START_DT) FROM employee_tbl T4 
    WHERE  T4.employee_id_ID = T5.employee_ID AND T4.END_DT = '9999-12-31')
    AND T5.END_DT = '9999-12-31'
```

For individual users its working fine, but when i commented out particular user, for  mass update, its showing error.Category   The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES INTO statement is more than one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED:

This really calls for an iterative approach - use a script to crawl through each record where END_DT='9999-12-31' and for each of those, it's much simpler to find the *next* START_DT.  Trying to do it all at once in a single UPDATE statement is intriguing and tempting, but not very practical.

Also, this looks like something you're doing to clean up your table, not something that should be run more than once.  It's not the best use of your time to come up with a clever, elegant solution to a one-time problem.

What *should* be happening is that every time a new record is added, the previous record should get a new start date.  This is also much simpler than trying to do it all retroactively.  Alternatively, you could forget about the END_DT altogether, since it's trouble to maintain that, and you can use a query to dynamically calculate it if you need to look it up.

That being said, and while I don't have an elegant solution to solve this in a single sql statement, you do have a few issues in your code here:

1. When you SELECT MIN in your T5 WHERE clause, you're assuming that at most there are 2 records per employee.  This would ignore 2nd record out of 3 or the 3rd record out of 4, etc.  Those records need end dates too, so that would be a problem
2. Likewise when you SELECT MAX in the criteria for your T1 query, you're assuming only 2 records per employee and you miss the middle records, if there are any
3. This isn't an error, just a style point: instead of the "SELECT COUNT(*)" subquery, you could replace it with an entry in the where clause: "T1.employee_id IN (SELECT employee_id from employee_tbl group by employee_id having COUNT(1)>1)"

Comment: Yes, I commented out both of the places where employeeid = sam334. Is (SELECT MIN (T4.START_DT) FROM employee_tbl T4  pulling multiple records....?

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott.. This is really helpful,I know this is not a good way of achieving the result.I will try to change it as per your suggestion. Thanks for your time,